# jCarousel in Ocassions WP Theme is Vertical on all Pages Other than Home

Tags: html, css, wordpress, jcarousel

You can see my site here:  http://www.fortysomethingbride.com The home page is gorgeous and I love the theme, however, on any page other than the home page the jCarousel is running vertical down the page and making the page unreadable.  (Click on any reference in the carousel to see what I mean.)

I used firebug to find the error in html.  But I don't understand coding enough to know where to make the change in the source.  Unfortunately for me, the developer has told me that he doesn't know enough to understand why I am having the problem.

Here is the correct code from the home page:

```
<div class=" jcarousel-skin-tango"><div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" id="mycarousel" style="position: relative; display: block;">
<div class="jcarousel-scroll">
<h3 class="featured">Featured Stories</h3>
<form action="">
<a id="mycarousel-next" href="#">Next »</a>
<a id="mycarousel-prev" href="#">« Prev</a>
</form>
</div>
<div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><ul class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1080px;">
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;" jcarouselindex="1">
<div class="img-title">
```

And this is what is on any other page:

```
<div class="jcarousel-skin-tango" id="mycarousel">
<div class="jcarousel-scroll">
<h3 class="featured">Featured Stories</h3>
<form action="">
<a id="mycarousel-next" href="#">Next »</a>
<a id="mycarousel-prev" href="#">« Prev</a>
</form>
</div>
<ul>
<li>
<div class="img-title">
```

I have identified the code that needs to be fixed, but I have no idea where to fix the error.  Is it in a php file or a css file?

I would be truly grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Colleen

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code in google's inspect element there is an error; 151Uncaught TypeError: Object# has no method 'jCarousel; under the ride the carousel section.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug throws the following error

`Failed to load source for: http://www.fortysomethingbride.com/wp-content/themes/occasions/scripts/jquery.js.pagespeed.ce.J2rPXwTExg.js`

And when i copy pasted the url in my browser , nothing showed up.